# Finding the set of weights for a representation of a Lie group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $V = \mathbb{C}^3 \otimes \mathbb{C}^3$ be a representation of $G = SL_3(\mathbb{C})$.
I want to find the weights of this representation in terms of the functionals $\varepsilon_i$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$, where $\varepsilon_i$ takes $\text{diag}[h_1, h_2, h_3] \in \mathfrak{h}$ to $h_i$.
Trying to work from the definitions $$V(\lambda) = \{v \in V : h \cdot v = \lambda(h) v \text{ for all } h \in \mathfrak{h}\}$$ seems very difficult.
When writing $\lambda = n_1\varepsilon_1 + n_2 \varepsilon_2 + n_3 \varepsilon_3$, there is no way to reconcile this relation with the action of $h \in H$ on $v_1 \otimes v_2$ to find nonzero $\lambda$ weight spaces.
I'm sure I'm missing something elementary but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: You might be mixing up Lie algebra versus Lie group representations. Anyway, first you should check that you understand how $G$ acts on each of those factors $\mathbb C^3$ in the tensor product, i.e. what weight vectors are there. Then, if we're talking of *groups*, if $v$ is a weight vector to weight $\alpha$ and $w$ is a weight vector to weight $\beta$, then $v\otimes w$ is a weight vector to $\alpha \cdot \beta$ (whereas with Lie *algebras* we would have $\alpha+\beta$ here). The problem is you decompose your weight $\lambda$ additively, but if dealing with groups things are multiplicative.

Comment: My comment quite literally said how to determine weight vectors in the tensor product from weight vectors on each factor, both in the group and in the algebra setting. What is unclear about that?

Comment: As in finding the weights of $G$ acting on $\mathbb{C}^3$. They are the functionals $\lambda$ for which $h \cdot v = \lambda(h) v$. Decomposing $\lambda$ additively like before (since this is weight vectors of $\mathfrak{h}$), then I supposedly have to require $h_1 = h_2 = h_3 = n_1 h_1 + n_2 h_2 + n_3h_3$, which can't be correct. This is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: Why would you have $h_1=h_2=h_3=n_1h_1+n_2h_2+n_3h_3$? -- Can you find a vector $v \in \mathbb C^3$ so that, for example, $diag[h_1,h_2,h_3] \cdot v = h_1 v$ -- that would be a weight vector to the weight $\epsilon_1$. In any case, if you already have trouble finding the weights in those basic representations, maybe you should ask about that first before trying your luck with a tensor prodict.

Comment: You're right actually, I've jumped the gun by doing this first instead of working through the basic examples. I think then the weights should be $\varepsilon_i + \varepsilon_j$ for $i, j = 1 ,2 ,3$, so each weight has multiplicity one. I think this is correct?